# How to change the address a pointer is pointing to in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

While experimenting with pointers, I had the idea to change the address a pointer. I tried the following:

```
int* pointer; 
&pointer = 0x28ff0d; //To point to an empty space in memory
```

But that threw out an error (Details: (here) in line 2, lvalue required as left operand [...]), so I guess it's impossible? I'm not trying to make a nullpointer, but litterally to change the memory address

Comment: `pointer = &thing_to_point_to;`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway?  You have absolutely no control over the memory you are pointing to that way and you have no idea what you may be corrupting.

Comment: `pointer = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x28ff0d);` Note that this is bound to lead you into UB land.

Comment: Unless you are working in a special environment where some addresses are specifically reserved, there is pretty much no situation where assigning a hard coded integer as the address of a pointer is the right thing to do. For those specific cases you have [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) but for your use case it's undefined behavior to dereference the pointer unless your specific platform happens to say otherwise.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I tried it, but it didn't point to the address I wanted it to do (Tested it with `cout << &pointer << endl;`)

Comment: That's because you printed where the pointer resides, not where it points to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obvious reasons, setting a pointer to a hardcoded address is a bad idea. But, you can do so by `reinterpret_cast<>`ing the address to the type you're assigning it to, like so:

```
int * pointer = reinterpret_cast<int *>(0xDEADBEEF);
```

or

```
int * pointer = &some_int;
. . .
pointer = reinterpret_cast<int *>(0xDEADBEEF);
```

Note that dereferencing `pointer` in this case is undefined behavior... but doing this might still be useful for something like debugging a use-after-free, where a sentinel value like 0xDEADBEEF would clearly communicate that you had already freed that memory.

Obviously the much more common, useful, and *safe* case for changing the address you are pointing to would be to take the address of a different (real) piece of data:

```
int * pointer = &some_int;
int new_val = 1234;
pointer = &new_val; // *pointer is now 1234
```

Comment: Even for debugging, you would have to be sure your implementation behaves correctly. While undefined behavior may produce behavior that "seems more intuitive" in debug and unoptimized builds, it's still UB.

Comment: My understanding is that as long as you don't try to *read* from that pointer, there's no UB (and thus suitable for flagging previously-deleted pointers in a debug build). Is that incorrect?

Comment: You can't dereference the pointer. Usually that means reading but it also includes writing. So I guess this is actually ok since you never dereference it.

Comment: Ah, sure, makes sense!

Comment: @s3cur3 Is it a coincidence that the address, if read like two words, spells out "dead beef"?

Comment: @Keheck 0xDEADBEEF is a traditional hex value for indicating a pointer in a specific "invalid" state. It stands out when you're looking at the value in the debugger. There are lots of other ["hexspeak"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) values like this (0xDEADC0DE, 0xBAAAAAAD, etc.); Robert ("Bob") Nystrom, author of [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com) prefers 0x1DEADBOB. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can never change the address of a variable. So whatever T is (be it an intrinsic type like int or double, a struct, a pointer or an array, the following is forbidden in C++:

```
T var;
&var = anything;   // WRONG! &var is not a lvalue
```

The error *lvalue required as left operand* means that you can only assign to something that can receive a new value, and the address of a variable is not.

Comment: But what about C++?

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable. Any variable has an address where it's located. So if you've declared a varible like e.g. `int x;`, then `&x` is the address where that variable resides.

A pointer is a variable which resides somewhere, but in addition it has a value, which happens to be an address of some other variable. So if you've declared a pointer `int* x;`, have written something to it, then `x` will represent some address you've written to it, and `*x` will be the value pointed to by the pointer.

So your syntactic mistake was using `&` where you should have just used the variable name, without `&`. After this is clear, be sure to read the other answers which explain further problems with your code.

Answer (score 0):

`int* pointer; 
&pointer = 0x28ff0d;`

This will throw error because `&pointer` is not an lvalue. On the left side of the assignment operator there must be an lvalue.